# How can I avoid changing image view to rotate when device is rotated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, rotation, orientation

How can I avoid changing image view to rotate when device is rotated. I have image view which i don't want to rotate when device orientation is changed.

Comment: are rotating all other views ?

Comment: i want my image view to not rotate when device is rotated but functionality should work in same orientation as device orientation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you want the whole view to autorotate, except for your image view, then you can basically just manually rotate the image view back to normal whilst everything else autorotates.

You can do this in `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`.  Apply a transform to the view you want rotated.

```
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
                                         duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"controlMovement" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    if( interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || 
        interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) {
        myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;      
    } else {
        myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI / 2 );
    }   
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Good stuff. But you have to check against current orientation, whether to rotate image to the right, left, or upside down. In this code you rotate only to 90 degrees and back to the original identity.

Comment: @bioffe: it seems like that would be the case, but that is the exact code I'm using in one of my projects, and it works in every case.  At the point willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: is called, the passed in interfaceOrientation is the current one.  Remember that the autorotation has already changed the orientation of the view on it's own, so all that needs to be done is leave it be, or rotate it 90 degrees.

Comment: @zpasternack Negative. Yesterday I found a bug in my very own software by looking at your code. There is an edge case. You will have to flip your device over X-axis to expose the bug. Let's say you are looking at  the screen, now turn your device in such a way that your screen looks outwards from you. iOS will perform 180 degree swing.

Comment: @zpasternack  (*OFFTOPIC*) And I like your blog very much :) I was forced to develop my own UIAlertVeiew replacement. I wouldn't if I knew these tricks, but know I am kinda glad I did, since it doesn't have these stupid imposed limitations of the original one.

Comment: @bioffe: nope, works in that case as well.  See, it doesn't rotate based on the current transform; it's either identity or 90 degrees.  So in the case of landscape right to landscape left, the transform doesn't change (it gets set to 90 degree rotation, which is what it already was).  (Also, glad you like the blog.  You may be my only reader.  :) )

Comment: You can replace the conditional in the if statement with UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check for `UIImageOrientation` and then make the change or give transformation.

Well else could help you better,its just my idea

Answer (score 0):

Easy. I'd create a rotation animation that would compensate the change of orientation 
in

`- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) toInterfaceOrientation` method.

Based on *toInterfaceOrientation* value you can calculate the angle for your rotation transformation.